# jQuery select this element, and the child class of this

Tags: jquery, this, parent

What I want to do is something like this:

```
$(".chat-wrapper").on("click", ".chat-wrapper li", function(){

$(this.name).hide();

});
```

the structure would be:

```
<ul class="chat-wrapper">
<li><img src=""/><a class="name">Name 1</a><div class="body"></div></li>
<li><img src=""/><a class="name">Name 2</a><div class="body"></div></li>
</ul>
```

so when you click on Name 2 it would hide that name class only. (my li element has more than 1 class inside, i want to be able to select which one I want)
(This is not the actual reason I need to do this, but it's a simple example)

Comment: Can you be more clear? Do you want a button that will hide it's parent class?

Comment: What do you mean by hide the name class only? Are you looking to hide the list item, or remove the class "name" from the link?

Comment: Just do `$(this).hide();` instead of `$(this.name)`

Comment: I'm confused.  What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to hide all elements with the same class(es) as what you clicked on?

Comment: Okay so this was just a simple example that I thought would explain what I want to be able to do, which is select certain classes or other elements within the element specified by (this). My thought behind it was that you could do something like, $(this+" .name").hide() or something similar to that.

Comment: @DylanCross All you need to do is hide the child of the element clicked - no searching necessary...

Comment: @DylanCross: `$(this+" .name").hide()` doesn't work, but `$(".name", this).hide()` will.  Is that what you want?

Comment: ahhh yes that is what i want, that works as it should! Thanks.

Comment: @Xander, Rocket is: $(".name", this).hide();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you're asking, but it seems you have multiple `<a>`s inside an `<li>`, and want to the hide just the one that was clicked on.

Is this what you want?

```
$(".chat-wrapper").on("click", ".chat-wrapper li", function(e){
    $(e.target).hide(); // `e.target` is the child element (<a>) you clicked on.
                        // `this` would be the entire <li>, because that's
                        // what the event is bound to.
});
```

EDIT:  To only hide elements with a specific class, you can do this:

```
$(".chat-wrapper").on("click", ".chat-wrapper li", function(){
    $('.name', this).hide(); // This is the same as $(this).find('.name')
                             // `this` is the <li> that was clicked on
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/LTPpJ/

Comment: Your $(".name", this).hide(); works as it should, I also updated my example showing what the li could look like for future reference.

Comment: @DylanCross: Added that to my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you just need to build up a class selector based on the value of the attribute

```
$(".chat-wrapper").on("click", ".chat-wrapper li", function(){
  var sel = "." + $(this).attr('class');
  $(sel).hide();
});
```

Note: As Rocket pointed out if the anchor can have multiple classes then you need to consider whether or not to do the operation for all, some or just one of the classes.  Here is the code to do it for all of the classes

```
$(".chat-wrapper").on("click", ".chat-wrapper li", function(){
  var all = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    var sel = '.' + all[i];
    $(sel).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Note `$(this).attr('class')` might contain multiple (space-separated) classes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with the .on() function. But I think what you are trying to do is the following.

```
$(".chat-wrapper > li").on("click", function(){

   $(this).hide();

});
```

Comment: the on function is setup as it should be, I use it a lot, it's better than live(). But Im not trying to hide the li element, in my example I would want to hide the .name class only, and not the li. (in actuality I want to be able to select any element within this element to add classes, hide, change or whatever it may be.